# How to set default value for multiple checkbox?

Tags: checkbox, phalcon

I have a form with several checkboxs

```
$activity = new Check('activity[]');

<input type="checkbox" name="activity[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="activity[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="activity[]" value="3">
```

When I edit info, I want to set checked value for multiple checkbox from DB, but setDefault() accept only one value?? I want something as following

```
setDefault([1, 2]);

<input type="checkbox" name="activity[]" checked="checked" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="activity[]" checked="checked" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="activity[]" value="3">
```

In view file I use

```
<?php echo $form->render('activity[]', array('value' => 1)) ?>
<?php echo $form->render('activity[]', array('value' => 2)) ?>
<?php echo $form->render('activity[]', array('value' => 3)) ?>
```

How to do this? Thank for your help!

Comment: How do you render this html? Show full code.

Comment: Sorry for some missing, I have just edited the above :-)

Answer (score 1):

you must set the setDefault method for every check instance.

```
$activity1 = new Check('check1',['name' => 'activity[]', 'value' => 1);
$activity1->setDefault(1);

$activity2 = new Check('check2',['name' => 'activity[]', 'value' => 2);
$activity2->setDefault(2);

$activity3 = new Check('check3',['name' => 'activity[]', 'value' => 3);
$activity4 = new Check('check4',['name' => 'activity[]', 'value' => 4);
```